# How to use Silverlight as a presentation layer for .Net assembly/code?

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, assemblies

We have following layers in our app all layers are built on .Net 2.0

- Object library[ used across all layers]
- Win Form client
- Asp.Net web service
- Business Logic library
- Database Access Layer
- Database

What would be the best way to move forward to have Silver Light as another presentation layer. I thought I could just add new Silverlight layer by referencing  Object library in Silverlight app and calling web service . But seems like its not possible. Refer [CLR Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110913203818/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrteam/archive/2009/12/01/sharing-silverlight-assemblies-with-net-apps.aspx).

Any architectural insights?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "Win Form client Asp.Net web", you make it *extremely* hard for anybody to give you a decent answer.  Not only does it not mean anything, it is an oxymoron.

Comment: I guess he just forgot a bullet point inbetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to reuse code, you have basically three options:

- Generally create all your basic class libraries as a Silverlight class library project, because it is the framework with the lowest set of features. Throw all references out except for **mscorlib.dll**, **System.dll** and **System.Core.dll**. You can then link such kind of Silverlight library in any full .NET project.
- You can link individual code files from another project with the "*Add as link*" feature (Right click project -> Add Existing Item -> Change "Add" Button to "Add as link"). That way you can create a Silverlight project and link individual files from your full .NET project. However that can get tedious if you have a lot of files and you often add/remove files and folders in your source project.
- To cure this problem, you may check out the Project Linker at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458870.aspx ... but I haven't tried it myself yet.